# What is the purpose of using the QueryInterface method? (Direct3D)

Tags: c++, direct3d

i understand what the [QueryInterface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method actually does- it only returns a pointer to a specific interface. But my question is, why would i want to use this method?

I mean, what is the difference between

`QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIResource), (void**)&Resource)`

and

`IDXGIResource * Resource`

aren't these pretty much the same? if so, why would i even need to use the method? For what reasons should i use it?

Comment: Think "multiple inheritance". Given an object of one type, it allows you to query if it is also an object of another type.

Comment: Oh i see. So in a way, it's basically a pointer that points to different interfaces right? So if i did this `device->CreateTexture2D(&SharedTextureDesc, NULL, &SharedTexture);   SharedTexture->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIResource), (void**)&SharedResource);` this would mean that, first of all, the `SharedResource` pointer will now point to the texture that `SharedTexture` points to right?

Comment: You can think of ``QueryInterface`` as COMs equivalent of ``dynamic_cast``, and remember that it can fail so be sure to check the HRESULT for failure.  Rather than using ``QueryInterface`` directly, consider making use of the [Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr) smart-pointer and then ``As`` method which wraps this up in a more natural C++ syntax.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

COM assumes that a single object will provide multiple interfaces, i.e. the interfaces will be fine-grained and you'll want to use more than one of them at a time. `QueryInterface` is how you get a pointer to those other interfaces on an object.

Your examples are incomplete. The first doesn't show that `QueryInterface` is being called from an existing interface, and the second doesn't assign any value to the pointer (it's an uninitialized pointer). A practical example would combine the two:

```
IDXGIResource * Resource = NULL;
pInterface->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIResource), (void **)&Resource);
```

To be robust you should make sure that the `QueryInterface` call [succeeded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687197(v=vs.85).aspx) before you try to use the pointer.

```
if (SUCCEEDED(pInterface->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIResource), (void **)&Resource))
    Resource->DoSomething();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that explanation!